# Why does my simple event handling example not work?

Tags: javascript, scope

I am trying to make a simple event handler.

(Note, I'm not trying to implement a full-blown publish/subscribe model; I'm just interested in why my example doesn't work as I think it should)

```
var myObj = (function () {

  var private = "X";

  function triggerEvent(eventName) {
    if (this[eventName]) {
      this[eventName]();
    }
  }

  // Setter / Getter
  function getProp() {
    return private;
  }

  function setProp(value) {
    private = value;
    triggerEvent("onPropChange");
  }

  // Public API
  return {
    // Events
    "onPropChange": null,    // Fires when prop value is changed

    // Methods
    "getProp": getProp,
    "setProp": setProp
  };
})();

// Now set event handler
myObj.onPropChange = function () {
  alert("You changed the property!");
};

myObj.setProp("Z");  // --> Nothing happens. Wrong
                     // Why doesn't my alert show?
```

I set the `onPropChange` property of my object to a simpler handler function but it is not being fired. I have debugged this and it seems that in `triggerEvent` the variable `this` is referencing the global `window` object. I thought it should reference `myObj` (which is what I need).

Can someone explain the error in my thinking and how I correct this? Help much appreciated.

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dkqUW/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code so you create the obj and then return it like this:

```
var myObj = (function () {

  var private = "X";
  var obj = {
    "onPropChange": null,    // Fires when prop value is changed

    // Methods
    "getProp": getProp,
    "setProp": setProp
  };

  function triggerEvent(eventName) {
    if (obj[eventName]) {
      obj[eventName]();
    }
  }

  // Setter / Getter
  function getProp() {
    return private;
  }

  function setProp(value) {
    private = value;
    triggerEvent("onPropChange");
  }

  return obj;          
})();
```

This way you have a reference to the object for the private functions.

Fixed fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/dkqUW/2/

Another way to fix it that you might prefer is to use the .call function:

```
function setProp(value) {
    private = value;
    triggerEvent.call(this, "onPropChange");
}
```

This specifies what `this` will be in the method being called (triggerEvent).

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/dkqUW/3/

Comment: I've tried this already - it doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/dkqUW/1/ Maybe I'm misunderstanding. If you think it works can you update my jsFiddle and add link please?

Comment: Thanks. This works now. But can you explain why my original doesn't work? I must have an error in my understanding of `this` in JS. And is your solution the "normal" way to solve this? I find it makes the code structure less readable as the object needs to be defined half way through the code (or rely on variable hoisting)

Comment: This is one of the ways of doing it, there are others. The original doesn't work because like you said `this` refers to the window global by default. Here's a good reference - http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this

Comment: @njreed See edit for a simpler way to fix the problem using the call function.

Comment: Thanks. I prefer the solution using `.call()`; much more elegant. The article link was very useful. I can see my mistake now in not realising the difference between calling `method()` and `myObj.method()`. Many thanks.